# How to grant a user UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, permissions, sql-clr

How can we assign **a user** , e.g.: the database owner (DBO) the UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission?

I'm asking it to enable a user to create an assembly and don't know the SA password, so `EXEC sp_changedbowner ‘sa’` can't help.

Any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only users mapped to a login that's a member of the **sysadmin** fixed server role can create and alter an assembly with an UNSAFE permission set defined. Therefore, to achieve your desired result you would have to add that respective login to the **sysadmin** fixed server role.

[BOL reference on CREATE ASSEMBLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189524.aspx):

> Specifying `UNSAFE` enables the code in the assembly complete freedom to perform operations in the SQL Server process space that can potentially compromise the robustness of SQL Server. `UNSAFE` assemblies can also potentially subvert the security system of either SQL Server or the common language runtime. `UNSAFE` permissions should be granted only to highly trusted assemblies. *Only members of the **sysadmin** fixed server role can create and alter `UNSAFE` assemblies.*

Comment: This is outdated and needs to be updated for current version of SQL server. So that others finding this from search engine do not get mislead.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
USE master
GRANT UNSAFE ASSEMBLY to [<login name>]
```